# Onhandleintent worked yesterday and now does not

Tags: java, android

Onhandleintent stopped being called

I have tried remaking the program, and it still doesn't work. I am pretty new to this, but was super psyched to have it working for the weekend. I just understand why it would just stop working...

My main method

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private List<ActivityTransition> transitions;
private ActivityRecognitionClient activityRecognitionClient;
private PendingIntent transitionPendingIntent;
private Context mContext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   System.out.println(getExternalCacheDir());

    mContext = this;
    activityRecognitionClient = ActivityRecognition.getClient(mContext);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TransitionIntentService.class);
    transitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


}


public void registerHandler(View view) {

    transitions = new ArrayList<>();


    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .build());


    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build());


    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.STILL)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .build());

    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.STILL)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build());

    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.RUNNING)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .build());


    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.RUNNING)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build());


    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .build());

    transitions.add(new ActivityTransition.Builder()
            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build());

    ActivityTransitionRequest activityTransitionRequest
            = new ActivityTransitionRequest(transitions);

    Task<Void> task = activityRecognitionClient.requestActivityTransitionUpdates(activityTransitionRequest, transitionPendingIntent);

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Transition update set up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Transition update Failed to set up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
 }


public void deregisterHandler(View view) {
    Task<Void> task = activityRecognitionClient.removeActivityTransitionUpdates(transitionPendingIntent);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            transitionPendingIntent.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Remove Activity Transition Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Remove Activity Transition Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

}
```

My Intent

public class TransitionIntentService extends IntentService {

```
private int activityBang;
private int transitionBang;

/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
public TransitionIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {
        if (ActivityTransitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            ActivityTransitionResult result = ActivityTransitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            for (ActivityTransitionEvent event : result.getTransitionEvents()) {

                Toast.makeText(this, event.getTransitionType() + "-" + event.getActivityType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //7 for walking and 8 for running
                Log.i(TAG, "Activity Type " + event.getActivityType());
                activityBang = event.getActivityType();

                // 0 for enter, 1 for exit
                Log.i(TAG, "Transition Type " + event.getTransitionType());
                transitionBang = event.getTransitionType();

                try {
                    ActivityWriter();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



private void ActivityWriter() throws IOException {

    String baseDir = getExternalCacheDir().toString();
    String fileName = "SentinelData.csv";
    String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
    File f = new File(filePath);
    CSVWriter writer;


   SimpleDateFormat date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G");
   SimpleDateFormat time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");

    String date = date1.format(new Date());
    String time = time1.format(new Date());

    if(f.exists()&&!f.isDirectory())
    {
        FileWriter mFileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
        writer = new CSVWriter(mFileWriter);
    }
    else
    {
        writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
    }

    String[] data = {date, time, String.valueOf(activityBang), String.valueOf(transitionBang)};

    writer.writeNext(data);

    writer.close();
}
}
```

Comment: how exactly is it not working?

Comment: Onhandleintent is not even being called....

Comment: I don't see you are scheduling that `transitionPendingIntent`

Comment: Isn't it being started here: Task<Void> task = activityRecognitionClient.requestActivityTransitionUpdates(activityTransitionRequest, transitionPendingIntent);

Comment: don't you need to start, or schedule task?

Comment: Oh, its on a button press.

Comment: which type is the `Task`? Can you show the package name?

Comment: I am such a noob, I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: what is the full package name of the class `Task`? How do you `import` it?

Comment: It comes with implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

Comment: So I think onhandleintent is just getting null. Which is wierd, because activitytransition is successfully being collected by task. the pending intent is always returning null for some reason...